# Terminal in React-Electron app

Tags: node.js, react-redux, electron

My requirement is to embed a terminal in my React-Electron app wherein all commands which I can run from bash can be run in the embedded terminal too.

Suppose I want to 'npm install' I want it to be possible through my embedded terminal too. Could anyone suggest possible solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure, but I bet you can create a interface with an text input, get the content from it, and use some function of NodeJS to run that content (witch should be a command). Then, just print the result on the screen.

You can use the exec function from "child_process" dependencie, like this.

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");
exec("ls");
```

For more details, you can check here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback